# Must Run Cell Twice to Display Values

Tags: bugs, inputfield, version-8

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 9**

---

What is going on here?

```
Print[InputField[]]
CellPrint[TextCell["my\"text", "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> True]]
```

[image]

If I insert the above code into a blank notebook and run it, only the second cell seems to appear.  If I run the code a 2nd time, both Cells are displayed.

How do I correct the code, so the `InputField` will be displayed the 1st time the code is run?

I am running Mathematica 8 on Windows 7.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I see both the input field and the string 'my"text' on the first evaluation. (V9.0.1 on OS X 10.6.8)

Comment: Can anyone confirm the issue in M8?  @m_goldberg This is what I get if I run it a second time  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt9EY.png

Comment: What your link show is what I see on the _first_ evaluation.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with v8 on Windows 7. A workaround is to add a tiny pause between the two lines, e.g. `Print[InputField[]];Pause[0.0001];CellPrint[blah...]`

Comment: I also reproduce the problem with version 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64. The problem doesn't appear with versions 9.0.1, 10.0.1 and 11.2.0 on the same machine so it seems to be a bug that was fixed in version 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce the problem with version 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64. The problem doesn't appear with versions 9.0.1, 10.0.1 and 11.2.0 on the same machine so it seems to be a bug that was fixed in version 9.

A workaround is to use `CellPrint` instead of `Print` for producing the `InputField`:

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[InputField[], "Print"]];
CellPrint[TextCell["my\"text", "Text", ShowStringCharacters -> True]];
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Posting the [comment by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27175/must-run-cell-twice-to-display-values#comment84665_27175) as an answer.)</sup>

I can reproduce the problem with v8 on Windows 7. A workaround is to add a tiny pause between the two lines, e.g. I have posted this as an answer, Simon.  It can be deleted if you would like to post your on answer.

```
Print[InputField[]];Pause[0.0001];CellPrint[blah...]
```

Comment: With this method I have to increase the pause to `0.1` in order to get it always working on my machine, the pause `0.0001` doen't work when the cell is evaluated *for the first time*.